# Get list of dates from two dates columns in sqlite3 (pandasql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, pandasql

I have a `date_from` and `date_to` . I want to get the list of dates in between these two dates, grouped by version.

| version | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ver1 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-07 |
| ver2 | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-11 |
| ver1 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-02-07 |

Result I want

| version | date |
| --- | --- |
| ver1 | 2020-01-05 |
| ver1 | 2020-01-06 |
| ver1 | 2020-01-07 |
| ver1 | 2022-02-05 |
| ver1 | 2022-02-06 |
| ver1 | 2022-02-07 |
| ver2 | 2021-05-09 |
| ver2 | 2021-05-10 |
| ver2 | 2021-05-11 |

I tried that recursive query but it didn't work properly :(

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(Date) AS
   (
       SELECT date_from from df as Date
       UNION ALL
       SELECT date(date, '+1 day') FROM dates WHERE Date < (Select date_to from df)
   )
   SELECT DATE(Date) FROM dates;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like following -

```
with recursive cte (version,date_from,date_to, next_date) as
(select version, date_from, date_to,date_from from gen_dt
union all
select version, date_from, date_to, date(next_date, '+1 day')
from cte c
where next_date < date_to
)select version, next_date from cte order by version, next_date;
```

Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Z7sKeHPUmo6fRPo4aAoqH/0).

Comment: Please feel free to accept/upvote in case this solution worked for you.